# How do I add router links in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was following a tutorial where you could take the star wars api and fetch data from the api to show on the website. In the tutorial, they basically show you to make a button and when you click the button, it shows the character info. But I want it to go to another page showing the details of the character using react router. Below is the code

```
import axios from 'axios';
import './App.css';
import List from './List';
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      people: [],
    }
    this.getPeople=this.getPeople.bind(this);
  }
  getPeople(){
    return axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people")
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data.results);
      this.setState({people: response.data.results})
    })
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.getPeople()
  }
  render(){
    const {people}=this.state;
  return (
    <div className="App">
     <List people={people}/>
    </div>
  );
}

}
export default App;
```

List.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import CharInfo from './CharInfo';

class List extends Component{
render(){

const people=this.props.people;
  return (
    <div className="">
     {
         people.map((p)=>{
             console.log(p)
             return  (
                <div key={p.url}>
                     <h1 className="char-name">{p.name}</h1>
                     <CharInfo charInfo={p}/>
                </div>
             )
         })
     }
    </div>
  );
}
}
export default List;
```

CharInfo.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class CharInfo extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            expanded: false,
        }
        this.open=this.open.bind(this);
        this.close=this.open.bind(this);
    }
    open(){
        this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})
    }
    close(){
        this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})
    }
    render(){
        const info=this.props.charInfo; 

        if(!this.state.expanded){
            return <p className="btn btn-info" onClick={this.open}>Show info</p>
        }
        return (
            <div className="user-details">
                <p className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.close}>Hide Info</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h2>Gender: {info.gender}</h2>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                    <h2>Birth Year: {info.birth_year}</h2>
                    <li><h2>Hair Color: {info.hair_color}</h2></li>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default CharInfo;
```

in this link, you could see the code in a codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-pine-lmhvn

Comment: Hi! You sandbox isn't quite set up properly. But, asides from that, I'm not quite clear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please Fix errors in your sandbox (they are import errors) and make sure the list is correctly rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to integrate the `react-router-dom` library in order to navigate to different "pages" in your React application.

Working codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/star-wars-api-8bbuf

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import List from "./List";
import Character from "./Character";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      people: []
    };
    this.getPeople = this.getPeople.bind(this);
  }
  getPeople = () => {
    axios.get("https://swapi.co/api/people").then(response => {
      this.setState({ people: response.data.results });
    });
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    this.getPeople();
  }
  render() {
    const { people } = this.state;
    console.log(people);
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={props => <List {...props} people={this.state.people} />}
        />
        <Route
          path="/char/:charName"
          render={props => {
            const { charName } = props.match.params;
            const foundCharacter = this.state.people.find(
              person => person.name.split(" ").join("") == charName
            );
            return <Character {...props} info={foundCharacter} />;
          }}
        />
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**CharInfo.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

class CharInfo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      expanded: false
    };
    this.open = this.open.bind(this);
    this.close = this.open.bind(this);
  }
  open() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }
  close() {
    this.setState({ expanded: !this.state.expanded });
  }
  render() {
    const info = this.props.charInfo.name.split(" ").join("");

    return (
      <div className="user-details">
        <Link className="btn btn-info" to={`/char/${info}`}>
          Show info
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CharInfo;
```

New component: **Character.js**

```
const Character = ({ info }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {
        <ul>
          <li>
            <h2>{info.name}</h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>Gender: {info.gender}</h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>Birth Year: {info.birth_year}</h2>
          </li>
          <li>
            <h2>Hair Color: {info.hair_color}</h2>
          </li>
          {info.vehicles.length > 0 && (
            <li>
              <h2>Vehicles:</h2>
              <ul>
                {info.vehicles.map((vehicle, index) => (
                  <li key={index}>{vehicle}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            </li>
          )}
        </ul>
      }
    </div>
  );
};

export default Character;
```

Comment: can you also show me how to add the vehicles data from the api too along with the already existing gender, birth year and hair color attributes?

Comment: It would be pretty similar. Everything is already in the info object, you could use the .map() function to iterate over it and render some content. I'll show you really quick. @helloTerminal

Comment: @helloTerminal see updated answer and codesandbox. It looks like you only have access to the vehicle url path. Not sure if there's an image you can use.

Comment: it's showing an url instead of the vehicle name in the app.. There's no images, only names..

Comment: how do i fetch the vehicle name from the url? using fetch() again?

Comment: @helloTerminal that I'm not sure of. You would need to become more familiar with the API and find out if they actually give you the vehicle name. :)

Comment: yeah they do. if they do, i would have to use fetch right?

Comment: That's right, you could use fetch to get the image back and update the component state with it. or create a separate img component.